# Half life and drug dosage

Tags: probability

3) A student is diagnosed with disease X. The disease requires to be treated by drug Q. Q comes in 200 mg tablets form. Given that half-life of Q in the body is 6.0 hours and that a minimum dose of 2.0 g of “digested” Q is needed to completely cure the disease X. It is recommended that at any one time no more than 750 mg of “un-digested” Q should be present in the student’s body system.  From the method of first principles, determine how many tablets all together will the student have to take and at what time interval to eliminate the X?.          15 mks

Comment: The number 3) is to emphasize that this is homework?

Comment: So what are your thoughts about this exercise?